# Invalid Scope Requested When Using Future Payments

Tags: android, paypal

I am trying to implement the Profile Sharing flow, and after clicking on  "Agree" button on the consent screen in the PaypalSDK. A dialog box appears saying "an error has occured" and the logs below are generated.

fj SN:11 PayPal Debug-ID: 48bf0a960c067 [sandbox, 2.13.1;release]
 request failure with http statusCode:400,exception:Bad Request
 request failed with server response:{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid scope requested"}

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?
I'm getting the same error. The only "solutions" online seem to be outdated, since they suggest to disable future payments and then re-enable it in the dashboard, which is not possible anymore, since all feature are just enabled in the sandbox, or am I seeing this wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution...
The green checkmark on the account state page, doesn't mean that something is "enabled" (although, those without a checkmark have a button called "enable"...) it just means that this feature can be enabled in this environment. If you want to check whether it actually is enabled you have to go to:

https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/

1. below REST API, click on your app
2. "Accept payment" needs to be checked
3. click "Advanced options" (behind Accept payments)
4. tadaaa here you can actually enable future payments...

Nice work PayPal...as always the worst design possible.